# Direct Kafka input stream and window(...) function

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using direct-Kafka-input-stream in my Spark app. When I use window(...) function in the chain it will cause the processing pipeline to stop - when I open the Spark-UI I can see that the streaming batches are being queued and the pipeline reports to process one of the first batches.

Derivations of window(..) function - like reduceByKeyAndWindow(..), etc. works as expected - pipeline doesn't stop. The same applies when using different type of stream.

Is it some known limitation of window(..)  function when used with direct-Kafka-input-stream ?

Thanks

Martin

Java pseudo code:

```
org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream s;
s.window(Durations.seconds(10)).print();  // the pipeline will stop
```

To be more correct: the issue happens only when the windows overlap (if sliding_interval < window_length). Otherwise the system behaves as expected.

Comment: Just guessing, but what if you set your batch interval in your `StreamingContext` to something larger than 10 (the Duration of your `window(...)`?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. I have narrowed the test case. The issue is reproducible only when the windows overlap.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Guess you have to ensure `sliding_interval >= window_length`

Comment: But this assumption is not needed for different type of stream. Just for direct-Kafka-input-stream.

Comment: I know consumer streams in Kafka prior to the redesign in 0.9.0 are blocking. I don't know for sure, but I am guessing: a) Spark does not use the new 0.9 consumer; and b) the other streaming methods don't rely on blocking clients. See here for more about the consumer redesign: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Client+Re-Design#ConsumerClientRe-Design-NonblockingconsumerAPIs